# Where do i find standard system icons of messageboxes via WinApi?

Tags: c, winapi, dialog, icons, messagebox

Where do i find standard system icons of messageboxes via WinApi? I want to create an advanced dialogbox (with details-extension) as WinApi resource, but I want to use the system default icons like:

[image: Standard system icons]

For .NET I know that i'll find them in `System.Drawing.SystemIcons`, but where do I find them using native C and WinApi? And how could I apply them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should be able to get them using [`LoadIcon`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). To get the question mark icon use `LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_QUESTION)`, the other identifiers are `IDI_ERROR`, `IDI_WARNING` and `IDI_INFORMATION`.

Answer (score 2):

Thats correct,

If someone needs here my code to set the icon and also to play the corresponding sound.

```
HICON hIcon = NULL;
if(mbdIcon == MBD_ICON_INFORMATION) {
    hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION);
    MessageBeep(MB_ICONASTERISK);
} else if(mbdIcon == MBD_ICON_QUESTION) {
    hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_QUESTION);
    MessageBeep(MB_ICONQUESTION);
} else if(mbdIcon == MBD_ICON_WARNING) {
    hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WARNING);
    MessageBeep(MB_ICONWARNING);
} else if(mbdIcon == MBD_ICON_ERROR) {
    hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_ERROR);
    MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
} else {
    ShowWindow(hPictureIcon, SW_HIDE);
}
if(hIcon != NULL)
{
    Static_SetIcon(hPictureIcon, hIcon);
}
```

May it saves someone some minutes. :)

Comment: I think this may alters the understanding of this question and this answer. Better it is a standalone answer.